# Does the current mssql drivers for php 5.6 work in windows 10?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-10, php-5.6

Does the current mssql drivers for php support windows 10 ?
same php code and drivers worked in windows 8.1. I cannot get it to work with win10
I am using php 5.6.4 and mssql drivers:

```
[PHP_SQLSRV_56_NTS]
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_56_NTS]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

Comment: What is the  specific error you get? " I cannot get it to work" is not a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly as far as i know
Instead use
sometime not.Instead use can use odbc_connect it works. tested. You can check out example :https://jewelhuq.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/how-to-connect-mssql-using-php/